# Inverse of augment method in Ti-84 Ti-basic for lists (partitioning a single list)

Tags: arrays, ti-basic

Can read about augment( here: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/augment

I'd like a program that is sort of the inverse of augment.
What I want to do is take a list, say L1, then partition it into equal length sublists and stores them into L1, ..., Lk for some arbitrary k. If need to be I can add the number 23 several times to L1 until I can partition it. I would like for each list to have n elements.

Example:

Take L1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

I'd like to partition it into equal sublists of length n = 3

L1 has 10 elements which is not a multiple of 3 so I add 23 twice to it to get:

L1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 23, 23}

Then I partition it into equal sublists of length 3 and get:

L2 = {1, 2, 3}

L3 = {4, 5, 6}

L4 = {7, 8, 9}

L5 = {10, 23, 23}

However this is one specific example but I'd like my program to work for any n so that I can go N->T:prgrParttition and it runs.

Comment: I've never found a good way to partition or split a list in TI-Basic, so I'm hoping someone posts a good response. In the mean time, I'll post an answer with my preferred technique.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most obvious answer for this question, but it's what I've always used when needing to split a list into multiple sub-lists.

The program prompts the user for a list (`L1`) and a row size (`A`) then splits the list list into `dim(L1)/A` lists with `A` elements each. The results are returned in the `Ans` variable in the form a matrix.

```
DelVar [A]Prompt L₁,A
{int(dim(L₁)/A),A→dim([A]
For(B,1,Aˉ¹dim(L₁
For(C,1,A
L₁(AB-A+C→[A](B,C
End
End
```